# I want to calculate a simple right shift in java, but I don't get correct answer?

Tags: java

I want to get answer 4, but my code prints 2. I don't know why?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(9 >> 2);
    }
}
```

[image: Image for my output and code]

Comment: Why do you expect 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will give you `2`

because

`9` binary representation is `1001`, and when you applied the right shift by 2 it will give you `0010`

thats why

```
9 >> 2 = 2
```

Answer (score -2):

9=0x1001
does that make the bit shift clear?